# Как установить пайтон библиотеку с расширение .tar.gz

Tags: python, pip, модули

У моего ПК нет доступа к интернету. Поэтому я скачал библиотеку с расширением **.tar.gz** с телефона. Вопрос в том что как теперь установить эту библиотеку?

Comment: Скорее всего никак, потому что вы забыли скачать зависимости этой библиотеки

Comment: А вообще https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014334